PackagingAssertion failed: new_time >= loop->time, file c:\ws\deps\uv\src\win\core.c, line 327 when running serverless app on Windows 10 VirtualBox VM
I'm trying to set up an application using AWS Serverless on a VirtualBox VM. Everything was going swimmingly until I tried to run serverless deploy on my app, when I was greeted with this error:
PackagingAssertion failed: new_time >= loop->time, file c:\ws\deps\uv\src\win\core.c, line 327

I've looked around and tried some generic solutions, since this seems to be a time-related issue, like syncing the clock in Windows settings, and checking "Enable Hardware Clock in UTC Time" in the VirtualBox settings, however nothing has helped. What are some steps I might take to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.
